# Custom action is rejected for built-in object type 'Link'

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to create a custom action 'View' for the built in object type 'Link' in my app, which publishes to the timeline, of a user 'views' a 'link'. However, on submitting this action for review, it is rejected with the following error:

`You are trying to submit a custom action which is not permitted. Please delete this action and submit a built-in version of this action instead.`

What is the a built-in action for 'Link'?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a OpenGraph action called `visited` instead and see if it works. Might be better than `view`.